# How we compressed videofile (all format) in android programmatically

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

i am stuck with the funtionality for the compressed video before upload to the Amazon s3.  i am looking functionality like the whatsup that compressed all the video of the gallery and camera after R&D i got FFmpeg library but that is increasing size of the app apk.Please there is any alternative t? Any idea about this problem